# referencing the *documentation* @return statement in node.js

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

All we speak here is about the code documenting.

Let there be two functions, `f1` and `f2`:

```
/**
 * @return {Boolean} always true
 */
const f1 = () => true;


/**
 * @return {Boolean} always true
 */
const f2 = () => {
  console.log('friendly wrapper of f1()');
  return f1();
};
```

Obviously, `f2` will always return the same value as `f1`. Thus, they may deserve the same `@return` description.

**Is there any way to reference the first `@return` statement into the second one, such that not to duplicate any comments?**

I expect something as simple as `@return $f1->@return`, but much more correct :)

Comment: If you're doing that you're documenting the implementation, not the interface. You should be documenting the function as a black box, regardless of how it's implemented internally. Some day the implementation may change and the return value ceases to be coupled to that particular function.

Comment: I fully agree with you, @deceze, but in my case ``f2`` and ``f1`` will always do the same thing, but with different arguments. ``f2`` will normalize some arguments and will always call and return ``f1``'s result.

Comment: It will do that *for now…* 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@see](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-see.html) tag:

```
/**
 * @return {Boolean} always true
 */
const f1 = () => true;


/**
 * @see f1
 */
const f2 = () => {
  console.log('friendly wrapper of f1()');
  return f1();
};
```

Cross file example:

```
############ FILE 1 ############    

/**
* @module myModule
*/

/**
 * @return {Boolean} always true
 */
const f1 = () => true;


/**
 * @see {@link module:myModule~f1}
 */
const f2 = () => {
  console.log('friendly wrapper of f1()');
  return f1();
};

module.exports = f2

########## FILE 2 ################

var f2 = require('myModule');

/**
* @requires module:myModule
* @see {@link module:myModule~f2}
*/

const f3 = () => {
    return f2() 
}
```

Comment: What if ``f2`` will be exported by the module, but not ``f1``? I cannot just send the reader to a ``f1`` function [s]he cannot reach. Your solution is acceptable in some use cases, nice try :)

Comment: You can create a module and refer to it across files, all the used files are required while using the jsdoc command